# Seprate sticky posts from main loop. #WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need your kind help. I want to seperate sticky posts from main loop (tempate : index.php) and want to add something after sticky posts before rest of loop. Please see the screenshot. Any tip for this custom loop? I'll be gratful.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKHkR.jpg

Structure is something like :

```
— These are sticky posts
– sticky post one
– sticky post two
– sticky post three

++ Add something after sticky posts.
— The rest of main loop.
– normal post one
– normal post two.
– normal post three.
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards
– Pomy

Answer (score 0):

Before standard loop in index you create your area create place where you want to load that "sticky" posts

in post page write this

```
<ul>
     <?php

     global $post;
     $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 'Sticky' );

     $myposts = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       </li>
     <?php endforeach; 
     wp_reset_postdata();?>
</ul>
```

This will get you posts from category you want, in this case you will get **5** posts from "**sticky**" category

Comment: it doesnt show random posts, it shows posts from category sticky, you must assign post to category and get it from there, here is link from wordpress.org how to get links

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

google it mate, look at the documentation :D

Comment: I told you after testing.

Comment: This works finaly, without assigning / create multiple category loop. 

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pomy/92ff60bbdf8fc07c3fec5977572772d8/raw/9d9e6dd3ba5de68b8c862a7c673bf9336b11b90c/Tweak%2520by%2520@pomy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 12, 'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'));
$stickyposts = new WP_Query($args);
while($stickyposts->have_posts()) : $stickyposts->the_post();
?>

    <!-- sticky posts (max. 12) -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <!-- -->
    <!-- here you can add random text or a horizontal line with a new headline or s.th. 
    <!-- like that. This is the exactly place between sticky and normal posts -->
    <!-- -->

<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 12, 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'));
$normalposts = new WP_Query($args);
while($normalposts->have_posts()) : $normalposts->the_post();
?>

    <!-- normal posts without sticky posts (max. 12) -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This will show 12 sticky posts on top of your page. After that you can enter some random text, or s.th. like that, followed by 12 "normal" posts, that are not sticky posts.

Comment: Two problems: ONE. It doesn't work with pagination.
TWO. : I shows 12 posts even if I change it to 4 from posts_per_page' => 6   for sticky posts. But it works with normal posts. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an incrementing variable (ie. `$counter++`) along with a conditional statement within the loop to trigger what you want after looping pass all(3) sticky posts.

```
<?php
$count=0; //Count is 0 outside of loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // Begin WP loop
if(!is_sticky()) : $count++; endif; // Start count for nonsticky loops

if(!is_sticky() && $count==1){ 
// Do stuff when the first none-sticky post is discovered inside the loop
// ie. Add a div, or insert a class name, etc.
}

// Here is an example of an actual implementation
if(!is_sticky() && $count==1): echo '<div class="not-sticky">'; endif;

// Loop countinues

endwhile; // Loop ends
if(!is_sticky(): echo '</div><!-- .not-sticky -->'; // Placed outside of loop or add inside a conditional statement within the loop to only run once
?>
```

...Years later, but I hope it may still help someone else who might be facing the same issue.